# Webpack loader for Phaser.io asset files

Tags: javascript, regex

The following is a webpack loader for Phaser asset files.  The way this is supposed to work is that it looks at the json string, and finds all of values with "url" keys in the json object, and transforms that value to a function call with that value as the parameter.  I need to assume any level of nesting of the json values.

```
module.exports = function(source){
  this.cacheable();  //comment this line out to run standalone outside webpack loader context
  var s = source;
  var re = /"url":\s*\".*,/g;
  var m;
  do {
    m = re.exec(source);
    if (!!m) {
      var path = m[0].split(':')[1].trim().slice(0, -1);
      s = s.replace(path, 'require(' + path + ')');
   } 
  } while (m);
  return s;
}
```

For example, the source could be the following as the parameter to the function (as a string)

```
{ 
    "level1": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "starwars",
            "url": "assets/pics/unknown-the_starwars_pic.png",
            "overwrite": false
        },{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": "assets/pics/spaceship.png",
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ],
    "level2": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": "assets/pics/spaceship.png",
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ]
}
```

and the return value would be a string of the following

```
{ 
    "level1": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "starwars",
            "url": require("assets/pics/unknown-the_starwars_pic.png"),
            "overwrite": false
        },{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": require("assets/pics/spaceship.png"),
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ],
    "level2": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": require("assets/pics/spaceship.png"),
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ]
}
```

How might I implement this in a more clear way that accounts for any nesting of the json objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation doesn't work!

Look at this snippet, where I extracted the standalone function:

```js
function exports(source) {
  var s = source;
  var re = /"url":\s*\".*,/g;
  var m;
  do {
    m = re.exec(source);
    if (!!m) {
      var path = m[0].split(':')[1].trim().slice(0, -1);
      s = s.replace(path, 'require(' + path + ')');
   } 
  } while (m);
  return s;
}
var source = {
      "level1": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "starwars",
            "url": "assets/pics/unknown-the_starwars_pic.png",
            "overwrite": false
        },{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": "assets/pics/spaceship.png",
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ],
    "level2": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": "assets/pics/spaceship.png",
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ]
};
document.write(exports(JSON.stringify(source)).replace(/overwrite/g, '<span style="color:red;">$&</span>'));
```

The result is that the `overwrite` key following the `url` one is part of the `require(...)`.
It comes from the way you expressed the regexp:

```
/"url":\s*\".*,/
```

Since the regexp is greedy the ending `.*,` consumes almost the whole string, up to the very last `,`. Then when you apply `split(':')` on it, you keep the `overwrite` attached at the end of your `path`.

To fix this issue, you'd better to use this regexp:

```
/"url":\s*\"[^"]*",/
```

Here is the same snippet, now with this new regexp:

```js
function exports(source) {
  var s = source;
  var re = /"url":\s*"[^"]*",/g;
  var m;
  do {
    m = re.exec(source);
    if (!!m) {
      var path = m[0].split(':')[1].trim().slice(0, -1);
      s = s.replace(path, 'require(' + path + ')');
   } 
  } while (m);
  return s;
}
var source = {
      "level1": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "starwars",
            "url": "assets/pics/unknown-the_starwars_pic.png",
            "overwrite": false
        },{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": "assets/pics/spaceship.png",
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ],
    "level2": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": "assets/pics/spaceship.png",
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ]
};
document.write(exports(JSON.stringify(source)).replace(/overwrite/g, '<span style="color:red;">$&</span>'));
```

Well, as expected the `overwrite` is not included in the `require(...)`.
But... now the `require(...)` itself is duplicated on the 2nd `url` occurrence, and omitted on the 3d one!

I din't try to look deeper on this second issue, because with the newly expressed regexp we clearly can do the job much more simply, like this:

```
function exports(source) {
  return source.replace(/"url"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"/g, function(match, path) {
    return '"url":require("' + path + '")';
  });
}
```

Here is this version working:

```js
function exports(source) {
  return source.replace(/"url"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"/g, function(match, path) {
    return '"url":require("' + path + '")';
  });
}
var source = {
      "level1": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "starwars",
            "url": "assets/pics/unknown-the_starwars_pic.png",
            "overwrite": false
        },{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": "assets/pics/spaceship.png",
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ],
    "level2": [{
            "type": "image",
            "key": "spaceship",
            "url": "assets/pics/spaceship.png",
            "overwrite": false
        }
    ]
};
document.write(exports(JSON.stringify(source)).replace(/overwrite/g, '<span style="color:red;">$&</span>'));
```